# How can you send a verify email template out in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

In the firebase object you have the following property in the auth token - email_verified. How can i utilise it to check and send a verification email template out?  Looks like firebase has the set-up for it but no information on how to use it... Many thanks for any response.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen. I see that you have edited this question and I know you work for Firebase. This is the 3rd similar question I have seen asked. Is there no answer?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about how to send a verification email, firebase.User has a sendEmailVerification() method.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#sendEmailVerification

Comment: Thanks, i presume you need the latest version of firebase? I'm using 2.4.2.